# SRGB/Linear correction for imported materials in Blender 2.80

Tags: import, color

I have recently upgraded from 2.79 to 2.80 and I can no longer use a third-party script to fix colours of imported materials.

I was using Rickyblender's **srgb_blender.py** that was posted on the [forums](https://blenderartists.org/t/help-please-is-there-a-fast-way-to-convert-srgb-values-to-linear/631849#post2802920), but that script now fails with **no attribute register_module**.

```
found bundled python: /home/bram/blender-2.80-d1cda823e0a8-linux-glibc224-x86_64/2.80/python
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/srgb_blender.py", line 456, in <module>
  File "/srgb_blender.py", line 447, in register
AttributeError: module 'bpy.utils' has no attribute 'register_module'
Error: Python script failed, check the message in the system console
```

Three questions:

1. Can Blender v2.80 switch how it treats imported diffuse material
   colours? Some models are coloured in sRGB, some in Linear. When
   importing (I use wavefront and dae) there should be an option on how
   to treat those colours.
2. Can blender v2.80 fix up the colours
   post-import?
3. How can I restore the srgb_blender.py functionality?

Full script:

```
# ##### BEGIN GPL LICENSE BLOCK #####
#
#  This program is free software; you can redistribute it and/or
#  modify it under the terms of the GNU General Public License
#  as published by the Free Software Foundation; either version 2
#  of the License, or (at your option) any later version.
#
#  This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
#  but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
#  MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
#  GNU General Public License for more details.
#
#  You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License
#  along with this program; if not, write to the Free Software Foundation,
#  Inc., 59 Temple Place - Suite 330, Boston, MA  02111-1307, USA.
#
# ##### END GPL LICENSE BLOCK #####



"""



by  Rickyblender 
on blendernaton forum

feedback from Padone

Thread  in pythpn forum

http://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?360140-help-please-is-there-a-fast-way-to-convert-srgb-values-to-linear&p=2802920#post2802920

"""



import bpy,bmesh
from bpy.props import *
from mathutils import *
from math import *

from time import time

last_menu1 = 'None'


# Ckeck Box Properties


# Float Numbers Properties


#####




class Panelsimple1(bpy.types.Panel):                        # This is the panel

    '''Panel'''

    bl_label = "Remove Doubles / Merge"                         # Header Panel's  name
    bl_space_type = "VIEW_3D"                           # in 3D view
#   bl_region_type = "TOOLS"                            # in tool shelf
    bl_region_type = "TOOL_PROPS"  
    bl_show_header=True  


    #   http://www.blender.org/documentation/250PythonDoc/bpy.types.Panel.html#bpy.types.Panel

    def draw(self, context):

        global last_menu1                             # Access global Var to find the last operation

        layout = self.layout
        scene = context.scene

        col = layout.column()
#       col.label(' menu color shade:', 'LAMP_DATA')



    # First  Operator
#       col.operator_menu_enum('view_3d.my_color1', 'colormenu1', 'Menu Selection')

                                                                        # Here the operator menu is displayed
                                                                        # 'view_3d.my_color1' is the bl_idname of the operator called

        col.label(' Selection : ' + last_menu1, 'QUESTION')
#       print ('in draw   ies panel  colormenu1 =',last_menu1,' Val =',eval(last_menu1))

        colorselect=""

        if eval(last_menu1)==1:

            colorselect="sRGB"
#           col.label('First point', 'FCURVE')

            print ('selected sRGB')

        elif eval(last_menu1)==2:

            colorselect="Linear"
#           col.label('Middle Point', 'PARTICLE_DATA')




####



#       print (' Color selection =',colorselect)

        col.separator()
        Txcolor=colorselect+ ' Color selected'

        col.label(Txcolor, 'WIRE')

        subtype ='PERCENTAGE'

        col.separator()





        layout.operator("custom.button1")


        layout.operator("custom.button2")





#####


class FIRSTOperator(bpy.types.Operator):                    # When an option in the operator menu is clicked, this is called

    '''Operator'''
    bl_idname = 'view_3d.my_color1'
    bl_label = 'Operator'

    # Define possible operations

    colormenu1 = EnumProperty(items=(
        ('1', 'sRGB-Linear', 'The first item'),
        ('2', 'Linear-sRGB', 'The second item')
                                            ))



    @classmethod
    def poll(cls, context):
        return context.object is not None


    def execute(self, context):

        global last_menu1                                       # Access global Var so we can later draw it in the panel

        last_menu1 = self.properties.colormenu1                 # Store the choosen operation / Selection
        print ('selection   shade=',self.properties.colormenu1[0])







        if last_menu1=="1":

            print ()
            print (' operator  BL  Diffuse  SRGB  to Linear  1')




        elif last_menu1=="2":



            print (' operator  BL  Diffuse  Linear to   SRGB 2')



        return {'FINISHED'}

#####




###


#   http://entropymine.com/imageworsener/srgbformula/

def s2lin1(x):

    a = 0.055
    if x <= 0.04045 :
        y = x * (1.0 / 12.92)  
    elif  0.04045 < x <= 1 : 
        y =  ((x+0.055)/1.055)**2.4

    return y

###

#x = 0.1

#z = s2lin1(x)


#print ('Linear RGB  to   S RGB')
#print ()

###


def lin2s1(x):

    a = 0.055
    if x <=0.0031308:
        y = x * 12.92
    elif 0.0031308 < x <= 1 :
        y = 1.055*x**(1/2.4) - 0.055

    return y

###















#####

#Custom Button  


class custombutton1(bpy.types.Operator):

    bl_idname = "custom.button1"
    bl_label = "convert sRGB colors"
    __doc__ = "Simple convert sRGB colors"

    def invoke(self, context, event):

                                                    # when the button is press it prints this to the log / Console
        print("  ####################  ")
        print("convert sRGB colors1")
        print (' $$$$$$$$$$$$$ convert sRGB colors    **************************')
        print("  ####################  ")

        global  last_menu1

        context = bpy.context

        mesh_objs = [ob for ob in context.selected_objects if ob.type == 'MESH']


        begin = time()
#       print('Start Time in seconds =', begin)


        print ()
        print (' operator  BL  Diffuse  SRGB  to Linear  1')


        for mesh in mesh_objs:

            print('repr =',repr(mesh))

            print("active_slot:", mesh.active_material_index)
            print ()

            if mesh.active_material is not None:
                print("active_material:", mesh.active_material.name)

            for i, mat in enumerate(mesh.material_slots):
#               print (' dir mat =', dir(mat ))
                if not i:
                    print("material_slots")
                if mat is not None:
                    print("\t[%d] = %s" % (i, mat.name))
#                   print ('material = ', mat.material)

#                   print (' dir mat =', dir(mat ))
#                   print("\t[%d] = %s Diff color = %f" % (i, mat.name,mat.))


                    for item in bpy.data.materials:
                        if item.name == mat.name:
                            nred1 = s2lin1(item.diffuse_color[0])
                            ngreen1 = s2lin1(item.diffuse_color[1])
                            nblue1 = s2lin1(item.diffuse_color[2])
                            newcol = (( nred1 ,ngreen1 , nblue1 ))
                            newcol = (( nred1 ,ngreen1 , nblue1 ))
                            print ('old Red =',item.diffuse_color[0],' New Red =', nred1 ,'name =',item.name)
                            item.diffuse_color = newcol


                else:

                    print("\t[%d] is None" % i)




            print()




    # P 41  53 65

        end = time()

        print ()
        print('Execution took : ', time()-begin, 'seconds')
        print ()



        return{'FINISHED'}    

###




####

#Custom Button2


class custombutton2(bpy.types.Operator):

    bl_idname = "custom.button2"
    bl_label = "convert Lin colors"
    __doc__ = "Simple convert Lin colors"

    def invoke(self, context, event):

                                                    # when the button is press it prints this to the log / Console
        print("  ####################  ")
        print("convert lin colors 2")
        print (' $$$$$$$$$$$$$ convert sRGB colors    **************************')
        print("  ####################  ")

        global  last_menu1

        context = bpy.context

        mesh_objs = [ob for ob in context.selected_objects if ob.type == 'MESH']



    # P 41  53 65




        begin = time()
#           print('Start Time in seconds =', begin)

        for mesh in mesh_objs:

            print('repr =',repr(mesh))

            print("active_slot:", mesh.active_material_index)
            print ()

            if mesh.active_material is not None:
                print("active_material:", mesh.active_material.name)

            for i, mat in enumerate(mesh.material_slots):
#               print (' dir mat =', dir(mat ))
                if not i:
                    print("material_slots")
                if mat is not None:
                    print("\t[%d] = %s" % (i, mat.name))

                    for item in bpy.data.materials:

                        if item.name == mat.name:

                            print (item.name,' RGB =',item.diffuse_color)
                            nred1 = lin2s1(item.diffuse_color[0])
                            ngreen1 = lin2s1(item.diffuse_color[1])
                            nblue1 = lin2s1(item.diffuse_color[2])
                            newcol = (( nred1 ,ngreen1 , nblue1 ))
        #                   print ('old Red =',item.diffuse_color[0],' New Red =', nred1 )
                            print ('New SRGB =',newcol )

                            item.diffuse_color = newcol





        end = time()

        print ()
        print('Execution took : ', time()-begin, 'seconds')
        print ()





        return{'FINISHED'}    

###














###

def register():
    bpy.utils.register_module(__name__)


def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_module(__name__)



if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

Note that Brockmann's fix works splendidly. Here are the before and after pics.

[image: before]

[image: after]

Comment: Can you please post the full script? Hard to find the right one there.

Comment: Tried to fix the code to make it work for 2.8 (ugly as hell): https://pastebin.com/SJrFg0uy Can you test it?

Comment: @brockman Works!

Comment: @brockmann it doesn't seem to work (anymore?) for me, as the script changes the "Viewport Display Color" but not the color in the node-tree.